# error CS1525 why does it happen?

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, syntax-error

I don't know why but when I'm trying to compile the next code I'm getting error CS1525 and every `)` at the end of every while command is being marked as an error:

```
static void PrintArray(string[] arr)
{
    int i, sum = 0, subb = 0, pow, x;
    char opper;
    Console.WriteLine("how many numbers does your calculation have?");
    i = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
    arr = new string[i];
    for (i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("enter num {0}" + i);
        arr[i] = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("arr[{0}] = {1}" + i, arr[i]);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("what do you want to do?");
    opper = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
    while (opper = +)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            sum = sum + Convert.ToInt16(arr[i]);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("your sum is " + sum);
    }
    while (opper = -)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            subb = subb + Convert.ToInt16(arr[i]);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("your subb is" + subb);
    }
    while (opper = *)
    {
        pow = Convert.ToInt16(arr[0]);
        for (i = 1; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            pow = pow * Convert.ToInt16(arr[i]);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("the resolt is " + pow);
    }
    while (opper = &)
    {
        x = Convert.ToInt16(arr[i]);
        for (i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            x = x / Convert.ToInt16(arr[i]);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("your resolt is " + x);
    }
        Console.ReadKey();
}
```

I will be glad if someone can finally explain that to me...

Comment: how about because when checking equality you use `==` not `=`

Comment: and you'd need the + and - signs in quotes as they are chars - `while (opper == '+')`

Answer (score 0):

Given the lines (for example)

```
opper = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
while (opper = +)
```

It looks like you're trying to compare the character input to an operator. You'll want to change the assignment operator to a comparison operator, and compare the character to another character, like so:

```
opper = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
while (opper == '+')
```

Answer (score 0):

user1673882 is correct here about the cause of the compile error. However, there are several other significant bugs you should be aware of as well.

As for the original compile issue, you have two issues with the following line (and all similar lines);

```
while (opper = +)
```

First, `=` (single "equals" sign) is assignment, *not* comparison. You want to use `==` here instead.

Secondly, `+` is not a character in this case, it's an operation. (In fact, the compiler can't infer exactly *which* operator it might be).

Even if you get this to compile, though, it won't work because all of your loops are infinite loops. Consider this example:

```
char myChar = 'a';

        // Infinite loop
        while (myChar == 'a')
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Test");
        }
```

How could this *possibly* get out of the loop, given that `myChar` will *always* be `a`?

A few other miscellaneous bugs follow:

```
subb = subb + Convert.ToInt16(arr[i]);
```

This could be shortened with

```
subb += Convert.ToInt16(arr[i]);
```

or possibly even

```
subb += (short)arr[i];
```

Also, I'm assuming this shouldn't be "+" since that's exactly the same operation you're doing if the operation is "+" (i.e. the outcome of "+" and "-" should be exactly the same).

```
x = x / Convert.ToInt16(arr[i]);
```

First, same cleanup as above:

```
x /= (short)arr[i];
```

Secondly, you never test for division by 0 here, so this might throw an exception.

Third, I'm not sure what type *x* is, but "short" is definitely *not* closed over division - i.e.:

```
short a = ...
short b...
// May not be another short
Console.WriteLine(a / b);
```

Actually, this applies to multiplication, subtraction, and addition to some extent too in this case since shorts have a finite size. Consider the following code:

```
short overflow = short.MaxValue;

        // -32768
        overflow++;

        // +32767
        overflow--;

        // -32768 again
        overflow++;

        // -32767
        overflow++;

        checked
        {
            overflow = short.MaxValue;

            // Now this results in an OverflowException
            overflow++;
        }
```

One more example:

```
short testArithmetic = 1;
        // This gives us the result that 1 / 2 = 0.
        testArithmetic /= 2;

        // Set this back to 1 for the next operation
        testArithmetic = 1;

        // This is 0.0 too!
        double testArithmeticFloat = testArithmetic / 2;

        // This gives us the result we'd expect
        testArithmeticFloat = 1.0 / 2.0;

        // This'll compile just fine, but you get a DivideByZeroException when you try to execute it
        testArithmetic /= 0;
```